# AES encryption/decryption implementation problem

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

encryption.py

```
# AES 256 encryption/decryption using pycrypto library
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
 
password = input("Enter encryption password: ")
 
 
def encrypt(raw, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    raw = pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
 
 
def decrypt(enc, password):
    private_key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).digest()
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))
 
 
# First let us encrypt secret message
encrypted = encrypt("This is a secret message", password)
print(encrypted)
 
# Let us decrypt using our original password
decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password)
print(bytes.decode(decrypted))
```

decryption.py

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
 
BLOCK_SIZE = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]
 
password = input("Enter encryption password: ")
 
 
def get_private_key(password):
    salt = b"this is a salt"
    kdf = PBKDF2(password, salt, 64, 1000)
    key = kdf[:32]
    return key
 
 
def encrypt(raw, password):
    private_key = get_private_key(password)
    raw = pad(raw)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
 
 
def decrypt(enc, password):
    private_key = get_private_key(password)
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]))
 
 
# First let us encrypt secret message
encrypted = encrypt("This is a secret message", password)
print(encrypted)
 
# Let us decrypt using our original password
decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password)
print(bytes.decode(decrypted))
```

i was learning computer security and learned AES encryption. i wanted to make a simple program that implements this encryption i found this program but we i run it this happens

```
Enter encryption password: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\AES testing\encryptionAES.py", line 31, in <module>
    encrypted = encrypt("This is a secret message", password)
  File "c:\AES testing\encryptionAES.py", line 19, in encrypt
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\Crypto
\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 178, in encrypt
    c_uint8_ptr(plaintext),
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\Crypto
\Util\_raw_api.py", line 242, in c_uint8_ptr
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

so when running the code the above error happens the result  should have been the secret password but am not getting that what am i doing wrong

Comment: the installing worked not sure how but it did. the error is now running the code it is not giving the result i needed

Comment: Consider this the first point of learning encryption: using badly maintained or insecure libraries will result in errors or, possibly worse, in loss of confidential information. Should not be too hard to convert to another well maintained library, Python has a few.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thank you i will take it under consideration

Comment: Great, because it feels like this error requires fixing the library instead of your code.

Comment: Perhaps you would have a better experience with [pycrytodome(x)](https://www.pycryptodome.org/src/examples).

Comment: This is copy&pasted python 2 code, at least the `pad` function is telling me that. It won't work with most crypto libraries, even modern and well-maintained ones. You should be working with `bytes`, most crypto libraries expect `bytes` objects (or possibly `bytearray` and `memoryview`). If you have strings you want to encrypt you should encode them using 'utf-8'.

Comment: Both codes run with Python**3** and PyCryptodome if `cipher.encrypt(raw.encode('utf-8'))` is used instead of `cipher.encrypt(raw)` in the `encrypt()` function. If you really should use PyCrypto: PyCrypto is legacy, buggy and no longer maintained. Change to the successor PyCryptodome, which also has a [padding module](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html?highlight=padding#crypto-util-padding-module).

Comment: Thank you @PresidentJamesK.Polk i will try what you have suggested

Comment: Thank you @Topaco i will try what you have suggested